# Getting Contact Group EMail address

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I have this code that gets the email addresses and names in the organization list.

```
Sub Email_Extract()
Dim colAL As Outlook.AddressLists
Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim colAE As Outlook.AddressEntries
Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Dim n As Long

Set colAL = Outlook.Application.Session.AddressLists

For Each oAL In colAL

If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then

Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries
    n = 2
        For Each oAE In colAE

            If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then

                Set oExUser = oAE.GetExchangeUser

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1).Value = oExUser.Name 'User Name
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 2).Value = oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress 'SMTP address
                 n = n + 1
                   Cells(n, 1).Activate
'if a contact group
            ElseIf oAE.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1).Value = oAE.Name
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 2).Value = oAE.AddressEntryUserType
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 3).Value = oAE.Address
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 3).Value = oAE.Name
            n = n + 1
            Cells(n, 1).Activate
           End If
       Next
   End If
Next
```

I can get the name of the contact group already. But my problem now is I cant get the contact groups' email address e.g sample.sample@mail.com. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the address entries returned from `AddressEntry.Members` collection.